# Insert a random image in mysql database using php

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to make a CRUD application. on the Create page I have to have three fields (title, text, category). the problem is that I have to make a method / function in PHP or JS that chooses a random picture from the "images" file and automatically loads it in the database along with the other 3 fields. then it has to appear on the admin.php page together with the other 3 fields.

Images have almost the same name except the last digit which differs (1-2-3)

I have no idea how to make this method/function.

my create.php page

```
// Include config file
require_once "config.php";
 
// Define variables and initialize with empty values
$title = $text = $category =  "";
$title_err = $text_err = $category_err =  "";
 
// Processing form data when form is submitted
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
 

    // Validate title
    $input_title = trim($_POST["title"]);
    if(empty($input_title)){
        $title_err = "Please enter a title.";
    } else{
        $title = $input_title;
    }
    
    // Validate text
    $input_text = trim($_POST["text"]);
    if(empty($input_text)){
        $text_err = "Please enter an text.";     
    } else{
        $text = $input_text;
    }
    
    // Validate category
    $input_category = trim($_POST["category"]);
    if(empty($input_category)){
        $category_err = "Please enter the category.";     
    } else{
        $category = $input_category;
    }

     // Check input errors before inserting in database
    if(empty($title_err) && empty($text_err) && empty($category_err)){
        // Prepare an insert statement
        $sql = "INSERT INTO informatii (title, text, category) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
 
        if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            $stmt->bind_param("sss", $param_title, $param_text, $param_category, );
            
            // Set parameters
            $param_title = $title;
            $param_text = $text;
            $param_category = $category;
            
            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if($stmt->execute()){
                // Records created successfully. Redirect to landing page
                header("location: admin.php");
                exit();
            } else{
                echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }
        }
     
    // Close statement
    $stmt->close();
}
}

?>
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Create Record</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style>
    .wrapper {
        width: 600px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <h2 class="mt-5">Create Record</h2>
                    <p>Please fill this form and submit to add employee record to the database.</p>
                    <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>title</label>
                            <input type="text" name="title"
                                class="form-control <?php echo (!empty($title_err)) ? 'is-invalid' : ''; ?>"
                                value="<?php echo $title; ?>">
                            <span class="invalid-feedback"><?php echo $title_err;?></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Text</label>
                            <textarea name="text"
                                class="form-control <?php echo (!empty($text_err)) ? 'is-invalid' : ''; ?>"><?php echo $text; ?></textarea>
                            <span class="invalid-feedback"><?php echo $text_err;?></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Category</label>
                            <textarea name="category"
                                class="form-control <?php echo (!empty($category_err)) ? 'is-invalid' : ''; ?>"><?php echo $category; ?></textarea>
                            <span class="invalid-feedback"><?php echo $category_err;?></span>
                        </div>
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
                        <a href="index.php" class="btn btn-secondary ml-2">Cancel</a>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You don't want to insert the actual images into the database, but just names which you can use as references later on. That way all you have to insert is the names, so simply strings. Standard thing, every tutorial will tell you how to do that.

Comment: @MarioAbbruscato Please don't link to w3schools. It's full of awful advice and is the WikiHow of programming advice.

Comment: I'm still stuck. I also added the source code

Comment: If you're just getting started with PHP and want to build applications, I'd strongly recommend looking at various [development frameworks](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/best-php-frameworks/) to see if you can find one that fits your style and needs. They come in various flavors from lightweight like [Fat-Free Framework](https://fatfreeframework.com/) to far more comprehensive like [Laravel](https://laravel.com/). These give you concrete examples to work from and guidance on how to write your code and organize your project's files.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To do it you need more than one step creating:

1. A simple html page to post 3 fields value and the image
2. A php file that receive the post fields and the image and save  into mysql
3. A simple admin.PHP page that shows 3 fields and image

if you already have the images on the server please specify it in a comment

STEP 1:

```
<html>
<body>
<form method="POST" action="post.php">
f1:<input type="text" name="field1"><br>
f2:<input type="text" name="field2"><br>
f3:<input type="text" name="field3"><br>
im:<input type="file" name="image"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

STEP 2: post.php

```
<?php

$f1=$_POST["field1"];
$f2=$_POST["field2"];
$f3=$_POST["field3"];
$im=$_POST["image"];

if ($f1 == "" || $f2 == "" || $f3 == "" ){
    die("Errors: fields can't be empty! Go back check the fields and try Again");
} 

//Saving image on Server's file system if any image

if(isset($_POST["image"])) {

  //Saving image with no checking nothing: filetype, mime , extention (it may be very dangerous in a real server exposed to the public)

  $where_save = "images/";
  $im_name = basename($_FILES["image"]["name"]);
  $tmp_name = $_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"];
  move_uploaded_file ( $tmp_name , $where_save.$im_name );
  
}

$h  = "localhost";
$u  = "username";
$p  = "password";
$db = "yourDB";

// Creating connection to mysql server
$conn = mysqli_connect($h, $u, $p, $db);
// Checking connection
if (!$conn) {
  die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

// WARNINGS ------------------------------------------------
// I do not care about security , please pay attention to it . 
// use some mysql_escape_string , or real_mysql_escape_string 
// could mitigate the violence of some sqlinjection attack

$sql = "INSERT INTO yourtable (field1, field2, field3,im_name)
VALUES ('$f1', '$f2', '$f3',$im_name)";

//executing mysql query to save data into it 
if (!mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {

   die("Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn));
} 
//closing connection  
mysqli_close($conn);

//Now we can redirect the user to admin.php  where we show data 
header("Location: admin.php");

?>
```

STEP 3:

```
<?php

$where_are_images="images/";

$h  = "localhost";
$u  = "username";
$p  = "password";
$db = "yourDB";

// Again creating connection to mysql server
$conn = mysqli_connect($h, $u, $p, $db);

if (!$conn) {
  die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

//now we want to read the data from mysql

$sql = "SELECT * FROM yourtable LIMIT 1"; //just limit to the first record
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
?>

<html>
<body>
<h2>Admin page</h2>
<em> hey every one can see top secret data here , Needs soma care about security!</em>

<?php while($d = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){  // LOOPING ?>
   
    <br>
    f1:<?= $d["field1"] ?><br>
    f2:<?= $d["field2"] ?><br>
    f3:<?= $d["field3"] ?><br>
    <img src="<?=$where_are_images.$d['im_name']?>">
    <br>
    <br>

<?php } ?>

</body>
</html>
<php? // CLOSING AND FREE RESOURCES
mysqli_free_result($result);
mysqli_close($conn); ?>
```

Now you have all you need . Have fun editing it with random images part ...
I hope there are no error (i have not tested it)

Comment: with a few minor changes it worked, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

this should get you in the right direction (saving the image src is enough), you of course will have to adapt the path to your image folder, and image name

```
$nr_images = 3;

$random_nr_index = random_int(1,$nr_images); 

$random_image_src = '/images/image-'.$random_nr_index.'.jpg';
```

Comment: im still stuck.

Comment: what is your current problem?

Comment: same as before.